# Help with wet venting setup in old house

Tags: plumbing, bathroom, shower, drain, toilet

I am helping out elderly family with their bathroom on the first floor. House is old, mid 40's. The upstairs bathroom is fine but it appears to me that the current cast iron plumbing on the first floor is not vented. They have asked me to remove the old cast iron plumbing and refit with PVC. I have never done something like this (experience is limited to changing water lines here and there, hose spigots, etc) so I'm asking you guys for help. I added a photo of my very rough layout.

The current plumbing has the shower connected to the lav which uses an S trap before connecting with the toilet and down to the sewer line. I have been looking into wet venting but am unsure of whether or not I can vent the shower through the vent at the sink. I know I can't vent at the shower as the sink would then siphon out. Therefore, can I vent both the shower and the sink, and tie in together somewhere in the attic before punching through the roof? Also, should I keep the line to the toilet in the current diagonal arrangement or do two long 90s to get to it? I know I will probably get reamed for this but there is no way an AAV can be used anywhere in this situation, correct? Please let me know if there is anything else that sticks out to the trained eye.

Many thanks in advance!

[image]